# How to make a string by loop in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle, loops

I'm here a newbie with a question seeking your help. So many thanks in advance!

I've got a table like this.

[image]

It's actually a string from A to B to C to D. And by the 'Start date', A is picked as the 'original one' as it is the first to appear. By that requirement, the table should be fixed like this

[image]

There are other strings like this in the table and I have to identify and string them correctly all.
Anyone here may help me to do it on **SQL Oracle**? I cannot work it out on a loop. Thanks for your care much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `HIERARCHY` query to update the table with the desired value.

**Oracle data setup:**

> ```
> SQL> select * from your_table;
>
> START_DAT START_  END_
> --------- ------- ----
> 01-JAN-20 A       B
> 02-JAN-20 B       C
> 03-JAN-20 C       D
> 01-JAN-20 X       Y
> 02-JAN-20 Y       Z
>
> SQL>
> ```

**Query to update the data:**

> ```
> SQL> UPDATE YOUR_TABLE YT
>   2  SET YT.START_ = COALESCE(
>   3      ( SELECT MIN(START_) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY START_DATE)
>   4          FROM YOUR_TABLE T
>   5          CONNECT BY PRIOR START_ = END_
>   6          START WITH END_ = YT.END_
>   7      ), YT.START_);
>
> 5 rows updated.
>
> SQL>
> ```

**Updated data:**

> ```
> SQL> select * from your_table;
>
> START_DAT START_  END_
> --------- ------- ----
> 01-JAN-20 A       B
> 02-JAN-20 A       C
> 03-JAN-20 A       D
> 01-JAN-20 X       Y
> 02-JAN-20 X       Z
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!